# Regular expression with .*? (dot-star-questionmark) matches too much?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
zabcd1>abcf2 abcg3"abch,abcj4
```

I want to get:

```
  - abcd1
  - abcf2
  - abcg3
  - abcj4
```

Get string with prefix is `(abc)` and suffix is a number, and only one group `(abc)`. Characters `d, f, g, h, j` can be replace by a complex strings, such as:

```
t\t img src=\"img\/x.gif\" class=\"iRe
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear - abch,abcj4 is definitely a string that beings with abc and ends with a digit. The more vague you are with what it is you want, the less likely it is you will be able to accomplish it.

Comment: try edit your question, is abc followed by a digit, is any letter followed by a digit or multiple digits, etc?

Comment: I have added some information

Comment: Can you clarify the require "Get string with prefix is (abc) and suffix is a number" please?  How many characters do you want between the prefix (abc) and the suffice (a number)? Your example of desired results shows just 1 character between prefix and suffix.  The your regex and the actual results allow for zero or more characters between the suffix and prefix.

Comment: SOrry for my bad requirement. I have just added some information. Please help. thanks

Comment: You are assuming too much about how to solve this problem.  I would ask the question again, but exactly what you are trying to solve.  Don't assume that `.*` matching too much is your problem.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you don't want `abch,abcj4` because it contains two parts separated by a non-word character. You were close:

```
abc\w*\d
```

`\w` includes all "word" characters. It is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  See http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet.

If you'd like to be more specific, you can take `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, which is a *character class* and remove the parts (for instance `_` or `0-9`) that don't apply to your matches.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches `abc` followed by zero or more anything's un-greedily `.*?` followed by digit `\d`

```
abc.*?\d
```

you want to match `abc` followed by zero or more (maybe) lower case letters `[a-z]*` followed by digit `\d`

```
abc[a-z]*\d
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? It is looking for abc, an optional set of characters that cannot be a comma or number, followed by a number.

```
(abc[^,\d]*\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use either the * or ? quantifier, not both.

if you want to check for 0 or 1 of a character, you should use ? so then your regex would become:

```
abc.?\d
```

the . will of course match anything, not just letters, so if you wanted the 4th character to only be a letter then you would want something like:

```
abc[a-zA-Z]?\d
```

Comment: I don't know what the OP is trying to do, but the *syntax* of `.*?` is perfectly valid.