# preg_replace is excluding ".html" from the replace clause

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using the following preg_replace() call to replace links with a new structure:

```
preg_replace('/example.com\/sub-dir\/(.*)">/', 'newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/$1.html">', $links);
```

It almost works, except it doesn't add on the ".html" to the end of the replace, so it ends up as something like "newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/page-identifier" rather than "newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/page-identifier.html".

I am sure it's something simple that I am missing, however Googling the problem hasn't come up with any useful results so I am hoping someone here can help!

Thanks in advance!

Edit: as an example, here is a link side of $links

```
<a href="http://example.com/sub-dir/the-identifier">Anchor</a>
```

The above example works if I changed the regext to (.*?) however the below doesn't:

```
<a class="prodCatThumb" title="View product" href="http://example.com/sub-dir/product-identifier">
```

It ends up as

```
<a class="prodCatThumb.html" title="View product" href="http://example.com/sub-dir/product-identifier">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `$links`?

Comment: @Ashley: please look at my edit as I solved that problem for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's about `.*`
Just add `?` to that like so: `.*?`

example:

```
<?php
    $links = "example.com/sub-dir/myfile.php";
    $links = preg_replace('/example.com\/sub-dir\/(.*?)/', 'newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/$1.html', $links);
    echo $links;
?>
```

**edit:**
@Ashley: sure, the question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional. E.g.: colou?r matches both colour and color (from [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)).

But, additionaly when you use it with ? it's the ungready method (this may help explaining: [Regular expression with .*? (dot-star-questionmark) matches too much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689504/regular-expression-with-dot-star-questionmark-matches-too-much) or this: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html)

So, to answer your qq:

```
<?php
    $links = '<a class="prodCatThumb" title="View product" href="example.com/sub-dir/product-identifier">';
    $links = preg_replace('/example.com\/sub-dir\/(.*?)"/', 'newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/$1.html"', $links);
    echo $links;
?>
```

the output for this link:
`<a class="prodCatThumb" title="View product" href="example.com/sub-dir/product-identifier">`
would now be:
`<a class="prodCatThumb" title="View product" href="newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/product-identifier.html">`

Comment: This worked! Could you please explain what the "?" does and why it fixed it so I know in the future? Thanks again!

Comment: @Nikolo It doesn't quite work... If the markup is "<a class="prodCatThumb" title="View product" href="http://example.com/sub-dir/product-identifier">" it ends up as "<a class="prodCatThumb.html" title="View product" href="http://newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/fast-and-few-gloss-leaflets">" somehow!

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the contents of `$links` for better understanding of the problem.

Meanwhile can you try:

```
preg_replace('#example\.com/sub-dir/([^"]*)">#', 
             'newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/$1.html">', $links);
```

Comment: Thanks, your regex works for the first example in my post but the second it doesn't change the link at all!

Comment: Actually it worked for both of your examples. If you want I can give you an online demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've just used [this testing page](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html) to check your regex, and it works fine with the example text you provided (`<a href="http://example.com/sub-dir/the-identifier">Anchor</a>`). Are you sure there's not something else that's creating a problem for you?

The testing site returns this: `<a href="http://newsite.co.uk/sub-dir/the-identifier.html">Anchor</a>`

Comment: Thanks, please check the original post for an updated example.